# Как обновить billingclient

Tags: java, android

Cлучилось так, что Google потребовал обновить библиотеку `billingclient` на 3 версию или выше.

У меня она была `1.2.2` (после того как я ее обновил на `3.0.2`), но случилось это !

"В программировании я разбираюсь плохо, только изучаю, но мне очень нужно это исправить. Подскажите, что можно сделать? Огромное спасибо!"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
public class Main0Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Home_AppTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main0);

        mBillingClient();

    }

    private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();

    private String load1 = "1";


    private BillingClient mBillingClient;

    public void mBillingClient() {
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {}
        }).build();


        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    //здесь мы можем запросить информацию о товарах и покупках
                    querySkuDetails();
                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();

                        if(TextUtils.equals(load1, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete_load1();
                        }

                    }
                }

            }



            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //сюда мы попадем если что-то пойдет не так
            }
        });
    }


    private void querySkuDetails() {
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();

        skuList.add(load1);


        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (responseCode == 0) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void payComplete_load1() {

    }

    private List<Purchase> queryPurchases() {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        return purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
    }
}
```

Comment: В ошибке написано, что у вас неправильная сигнатура метода, прочитайте внимательно сообщение об ошибке, там всё доходчиво объяснено

Comment: Спасибо  за помощь, вроде как нужно что-то объявить абстрактным только как это сделать и что конкретно не понятно (

Comment: нет, абстрактным класс не надо делать, вам нужно другой интерфейс определить, внимательно прочитайте сигнатуру метода, который требуется и сравните с тем что у вас, почему у вас первый аргумент int?